# Adjust the css of divs in a loop on page load

Tags: jquery, css

I have a loop that outputs a bunch of boxes with masonry containing post excerpts.

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
     <img src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
      <h3>//title output with php</h3>
  </div>
</div>

.image {
   position:relative;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   z-index:100;
}
.box:hover .image {
   margin-top:-30px;
}
.info {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   z-index:99;
}
```

Ok so what I have here is a div containing the thumb for the post and then a div that I hide under it that contains the title. To reveal the title I give `.image` a negative top margin but my problem is that `.info` varies in height. So I need to grab the height of each `.info` with jquery on page load and then use that to set the negative `margin-top` of each corresponding `.image`.

Something like this but obviously this isn't right.

```
 function pageLoad() {
   var height = $(".info").height();
   $(".box:hover .image").css("margin-top", height );
 }
```

So how can I do this for each individual box in the loop?

Comment: Think you may be looking for .each() command in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what your looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').each(function () {
         var height = $(this).children('.info').height();
         $(this).children('.image').css('margin-top', height);
    });
});
```

I did not see the hover part before, maybe your looking something more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').hover(function () {
        var height = $(this).children('.info').height();
        $(this).children('.image').css('margin-top', height);
    });
});
```

Comment: Two questions. Do I need to add pageLoad or Document ready? And do I need to add the script beneath the loop? Just adding this didn't effect anything.

Comment: You should put this inside your document ready.  I edited the post.  The .each loops through each box finds the child info gets the height and assigns it to child image.

Comment: One thing I would point out is in my experience messing with negative margins often leads to trouble down the road.  However I did not completely understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok this works the way it is but I need to set the css of .box:hover .image not .image. When I add .box:hover it doesn't work. Know why that is?

Comment: Add an "alert(height);" after setting the height and make sure you are getting what you expected.  I tested locally and put some breaks in my different info blocks and it indeed returns the different heights.  You may have some other CSS issues.